# move data folder and drive mysql centos

Tags: mysql

i need to move the data to a different folder and drive on my cent os db server.

i added new hard drive (since we ran low on space),

i have a 1tb of hard drive and i have a new 2tb i want to put the data on on the same server (dedicated server hosted in a datacenter)

i would like to know what is the easy way to migrate the data without losing any data?

currently i have the data located in: `/var/lib/mysql/` on cent os. `mysql version is 5.1`

Comment: @abdelsaid no, im using myisam

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Step 1**

First setup your drive (assumed it's mounted and setup correctly in the fstab) and create new MySQL directory:

`sudo mkdir /path/to/new/mysql`

Make sure this folder has the right permissions:

`chown -R mysql:mysql /data/mysql`

Now here you can shutdown the service while copying data. Copy the data from the current data directory to new data directory, example:.

`sudo cp -R /var/lib/mysql/* /path/to/new/mysql/`

or you can copy individually each databases if you prefer or if you feel safe, you can move the folder using the `mv` command.

**Step 2**

You can change the location of your MySQL data in your `my.cnf`. If you don't know where this file is, you can run the command:

`locate my.cnf`

This will give you the path of where the my.cnf is located. Then edit the file:

`sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf` (of course you have to replace with your path)

Now look for `datadir = /var/lib/mysql` and update to `datadir = /path/to/new/mysql`.

Then restart mysql

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart`

After few days/weeks, if you feel comfortable you can remove the old folder (/var/lib/mysql) or backup everything inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want shutdown during migration, I would setup a master-master replication to chroot environment on 2tb with mysql (same version) in it, then when on sync turn the 1tb off and you got a working chroot environment.

If you don't want to use chroot environment, change the my.cnf (not the chroot one) to point to where you want to store your mysql files on 2tb disk and disable replication. Then turn off the chroot environment and move the data to what you have in my.cnf, the move here will not take even a second because it's on the same disk. Restart mysql.

This is little bit complex to do, you can play with this in local vm enironment first.